# C# WPF add KeyBinding events in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress

I am displaying a website to users of my C# application using a `ChromiumWebBrowser` provided by the `CefSharp` library.

I am trying to add functionality to allow the users to 'zoom in/out' using keyboard shortcuts, i.e. `CTRL +`/ `CTRL -`.

I have managed to add a `KeyboardListener` to the embedded browser using the 'Low Level Global Keyboard Hook/ Sink available at: http://www.dylansweb.com/2014/10/low-level-global-keyboard-hook-sink-in-c-net/

At the moment, my application will 'zoom in' on the browser, when the browser is 'in focus', and the user presses '+' on the keyboard. I've done this using:

```
private void _listener_OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyPressed == Key.Add)
    {
        zoomInExecuted();
    }
}
```

What I actually want, is only to allow the zoom in when the users holds either 'CTRL' key down, and then presses '+'.

I've written the following method in my C# (this is the method being called:

```
private void _listener_OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e.KeyPressed.ToString());

    if(e.KeyPressed == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        leftCtrlDown = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("LeftCtrl pressed, leftCtrlDown should be true: ", leftCtrlDown.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        leftCtrlDown = false;
    } 

    if(e.KeyPressed == Key.RightCtrl)
    {
        rightCtrlDown = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("RightCtrl pressed, rightCtrlDown should be true: ", rightCtrlDown.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        rightCtrlDown = false;
    }

    if((leftCtrlDown == true)) //&& (e.KeyPressed == Key.Add)) 
    {
        if (e.KeyPressed == Key.Add)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Ctrl & + pressed, 'zoomInExecuted()' should be called ");
            zoomInExecuted();
        }
    }else if((rightCtrlDown == true)) //&& (e.KeyPressed == Key.Add))
    {
        if (e.KeyPressed == Key.Add)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("rightCtrl & + pressed, 'zoomInExecuted()' should be called ");
            zoomInExecuted();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this method using the `<KeyBinding>` tag on the `<Grid>` in which the browser is displayed in my XAML:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="LeftCtrl" Command="{Binding _listener_OnKeyPressed}"></KeyBinding>
```

But the problem I'm having with this is: although the application detects when the 'CTRL' key is pressed (the debug is written to the console), it seems that it then can't detect the press on the second key (the '+' key).

I tried adding a second listener, that is called inside the first listener, only when either of the `leftCtrlDown` or `rightCtrlDown` booleans are true (i.e. when the user is pressing either CTRL key), but the application still doesn't seem to detect the press of a second key...

How can I make my app 'listen' for a press to another key, while it's already acknowledging that one key is currently being pressed down?

**Edit**

I've tried doing what was suggested in the answer, and now have in my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
    ....
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Agent"
    ... >

    <Window.Resources>
        ...
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="grid">
        ...
        <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" MinHeight="900" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1205" Width="Auto" Margin="5,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" >
            <Grid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Add" Command="{Binding _listener_OnKeyPressed}"></KeyBinding>
            </Grid.InputBindings>
            ...
            <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" ...>
                <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Add">
                    <KeyBinding.Command>
                        <local:Zoom Executed="zoomInExecuted" />
                    </KeyBinding.Command>
                </KeyBinding>
            </cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser.InputBindings>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    ...
</Window>
```

The `Zoom.cs` class that I've added is as follows:

```
namespace Agent
{
    class Zoom : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler<object> Executed;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (Executed != null)
                Executed(this, parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I'm getting a compile error in the XAML, on the line:

```
                                            <local:Zoom Executed="zoomInExecuted" />
```

which says:

> The name "Zoom" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Agent".

even though it clearly does.

Comment: `LeftCtrl` is a Modifier too, you can't have a shortcut for Ctrl + LeftCtrl

Comment: Do you mean in the XAML? I've tried changing that to: `<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Add" Command="{Binding _listener_OnKeyPressed}"></KeyBinding>` but I get the same issue... my console shows that CTRL is pressed when I press it, then shows that + is pressed when I press that, but the zoomInExecuted() function doesn't appear to be called..

Comment: Zoom probably needs to be public.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line can't work:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="LeftCtrl" Command="{Binding _listener_OnKeyPressed}"/>
```

`KeyBinding.Command` expects an object implementing `ICommand`, you are binding it to a method.

A basic implementation of the `ICommand` interface would look something like this:

```
class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler<object> Executed;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Executed != null)
            Executed(this, parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Add">
       <KeyBinding.Command>
           <local:SimpleCommand Executed="SimpleCommand_OnExecuted"/>
       </KeyBinding.Command>
    </KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void SimpleCommand_OnExecuted(object sender, object e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("SimpleCommand Executed");
}
```

Usually you would use [Commanding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to define the Command in code and use it in XAML. When you bind that Command to a `KeyBinding`, `Button` or `MenuItem` (or something else), the `CanExecute` method of your implementation can be used to disable the command (and therefore disabling the Element it's bound to).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code I have 'works', but only if I want the keyboard shortcut to consist of one key- i.e. if I call the 'zoom' method just when pressing '+' on the keyboard, the view displayed on the GUI will zoom in- what I'm looking for, is a way to call this event only when both 'CTRL' and '+' are pressed. I don't see how the code you have written in your answer addresses this? Could you explain it to me further?

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems my class would have to inherit from `ICommand`? I can't do that, as I'm already inheriting from `Window`, due to other features provided by my application. How would I use `ICommand` with my existing code? How would passing an `ICommand` to my application when the keyboard is used differ from passing it a method?

Comment: What? No! The window doesn't have to inherit from `ICommand`. Your **Command** has to. I've already supplied a simple implementation (`SimpleCommand`). You simply follow that pattern and instead of `SimpleCommand_OnExecuted` you provide your own event handlers for each `KeyBinding` (e.g. `ZoomIn_OnExecuted`)

Comment: What is the `class SimpleCommand : ICommand` code block you've written showing? That's what made me think that I would have to make my class inherit from `ICommand`... Do I need to write a class that implements the `ICommand` interface, and then call that from the `CTRL+` keypress in the XAML? I don't see where/ how I should implement the code you've written in `class SimpleCommand`?

Comment: Just put it in a .cs file, reference the namespace in xaml (`xmlns:local=whatever`) and use it.

Comment: Ok thanks- I've given that a go, but now get a `name does not exist in the namespace` compile error in my XAML when trying to use the new `.cs` class that I've added...

Comment: I've updated my OP to show the changes I've made, following what you've suggested.

Comment: You wrote `Agent` and used namespace `RiviamAgent`

Comment: That was a copy paste error on my part- the two do match... I've updated the code quoted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only hooking the WM_KEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYDOWN messages.  You need to also hook the WM_KEYUP and WM_SYSKEYUP messages.  In order to determine if the CTRL key is currently being pressed, you must set you leftCtrlDown = true when they press the key, and set leftCtrlDown = false when they *release* the key. Your code sets leftCtrlDown = false when they press any key other than control.  That logic is incorrect.

Looking at the linked article, you will need to modify HookCallback() to listen for WM_KEYUP and WM_SYSKEYUP.  Then you will either need to add another event for key up, or add a flag into the KeyPressedArgs to indicate if the event is being fired for key up or key down.  Either way.